# Liferay Spring Mvc Portlet

Tags: spring, liferay

In Liferay Spring Mvc Project I am getting one error in liferay

> Portlet not register

and the solution I got from net is

> Remove portlet.jar from lib folder of project.

After removing portlet.jar file  i got the error like

> Context inilizatian failed(spring error)

Can you help me regarding this error?

Comment: show us a bit more of you console log.

Comment: and tell us which version of liferay do you use.

Answer (score 0):

You must build portlet by using ant build, if you build to war file normally, portlet will not run. in the portlet project use the build.xml, then build it 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzUUB.png)